# Is it possible to use energy from past trauma to be a payment for current spellwork

Tags: magic, energy

I've endured some pretty horrific things in my past. There's a lot of trauma and I don't know if I can say bad luck? It's possible but the circumstances were very unfortunate and definitely unfair. So since we borrow energy is it able to use the energy from past trauma and use it in Magick? I'm just now at age 42 discovered I have an amazing gift. And I wonder if there's a way to utilize the energy from past events and turn it into something that works in my favor during my spellwork?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome Berekicent. We help design fictional worlds whereas you seem to have a real-life question related to pagan beliefs. Unfortunately our pagan stack hasn't yet gotten off the ground, but if I were to deal with your question *as if* you were creating a fictional world, I'd say yes. Many magic systems even in popular culture are based on focusing strong emotional energy - take Magneto in X-Men: First Class, when he'd learned to come to terms with his past traumas, and when he was able to call to mind all the pain, the joy - the full range of human emotions, he achieved peak power.

Comment: Whereas Gene Grey was in serious danger of being overcome by them. Control and acceptance vs unconstrained release - finding a balance is the way. Now I'm voting to close as off-topic, but you're welcome to [edit] after taking our [tour] and reading up in the [help] about how we work to get it opened as on-topic.

Comment: Yes. I've definitely used dents and body damage from past wrecks to fuel my car... haven't had to fill the tank for months at this point. All you have to do is imagine that damage is energy, and voila, magic happens.

Answer (score 2):

**Coping with trauma may entail the discovery of new energy sources, which can then be used for other purposes.**

Trauma and trying experiences are not in themselves sources of power or strength.  Too often these experiences (and stressful or counterproductive coping mechanisms) continue to be an energy drain on individuals long into the future.  One cannot turn to unresolved (or unrecognized) past trauma as a source for help.

But persons who recognize and successfully deal with trauma often do so by developing new abilities or abilities they had: patience, self-awareness, meditation, focus, forgiveness and others.  There are various paths.  These abilities may or may not be recognized to be a consequence of the trauma.  It depends on how they come to be.

For a story I like the idea of the character tapping old trauma and consequent recovery and strength as a source of power.  Flashbacks / backstory is good grist for the literary mill and gives the author a chance to deepen the character.

Comment: Agreed, trauma can be a powerful motivator to explore new ways of dealing with today. It also helps in breaking free from old ways of thinking about society and the world around us which can enhance creativity. "They lied to me about that, what else did they lie to me about?"

Answer (score 0):

### Only while you remain traumatised

Many current theories of PTSD/trauma posit that the way in which trauma differs from non-traumatic memories of horrific events is its feature of being unresolved. As a result, the traumatic event is not "remembered", with the narrative detachment that characterises our understanding of our own life-story, but "re-experienced", with the whole body replicating those physical and cognitive responses that were originally triggered by the now-past event, like adrenaline surges, depersonalisation, panic, etc.

If strong emotions fuel your magic system, then trauma provides a mechanism to invoke incredibly strong, "real" emotions *in the absence of a real-world cause*, just by bringing the traumatic memory to mind and allowing the trauma response to unfold. It would be horrific and re-traumatising, but much more potent than non-traumatic memories.

If you are interested in trauma processing in real life, I found [this book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Body_Keeps_the_Score) very good.